Time Complexity of Multiway System
I was wondering what the time complexity for the implementation of a Multiway System would be. For reference, we can implement a MultiwaySystem using the Resource Function
ResourceFunction["MultiwaySystem"][rules, init, step]

There is, however, an even more efficient implementation of the MultiwaySystem — created by Stephen Wolfram and Jonathan Gorard
MultiwayGrowthListHashSet[rule_, init_List, t_] := 
 Last /@ NestList[
   Function[
    s, {Join[First[s], #], #} &[
     Normal[CreateDataStructure["HashSet"]["Union", 
        Flatten[StringReplaceList[Last[s], rule]]]["Complement", 
       First[s]]]]], {{}, init}, t]

I was wondering what the time complexity for this function would be. I know how to calculate the time complexity of functions in general, but I'm unsure about the time complexity of the CreateDataStructure function and the Normal function. Also, I know that the implementation of the MultiwaySystem is highly dependent on the rules that we're using, so for reference, I'm providing a rule
rule = {"A"->"ABAB","B"->"A"}; init = {"ABA"};

Now,
Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[
  MultiwayGrowthListHashSet[rule, init, step]], {step, 1, 10}]

Gives us
0.034022, 0.117482, 0.577674, 3.364757} 

Visualizing this gives us

I've also looked into the BenchmarkPlot[] function, but that gives wonky results.
Any help will be much appreciated!
